# Silently installing Itunes with other application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, itunes, setup-project

Can we silently install Itunes with any commercialized application(.exe) made in Visual Studio? Does apple have any restrictions on silently installing Itunes?

How can we silently install another application with a setup made from Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Google showed me this in the first result for "itunes windows silent"; does this help? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2729053?tstart=0

Comment: @ChrisForrence Can I use silent installtion if my application is commercialized?

Comment: From a licensing perspective? You'd have to ask a lawyer for that, not a programmer. As for the 'how', though, it looks like that link should help.